# Get background color of dynamically populated table cells on mousehover using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on hotel monitoring project. I have a dynamically populated table whose cell represent a room and its status. The background-colour of the cell is set inline based on this status. I use Jquery to enlarge each cell on mouse hover and is successfully done. But my hovered cell is transparent. Is there any way i can get the background color of the dynamically populated cell. I used 'for' loop to iterate and fill the table and setting background-color.

```
          foreach ($member as $result) {                    
                    $room = $result->ID;

                    if($result->Status === "staff"){
                        $color = "#008000";                                
                    }elseif ($result->Status === "guest"){
                        $color = "#FF0000";
                    }else{
                         $color = "#0066FF";
                    }
<td style="background-color:<?php echo $color ?>">
 <div class="outer-box" style="background-color:<?php echo $color ?>">
   <div class="box">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>roomdetails_controller/roomdetails_function/<?php echo $room;?>"<?php echo "<p>ROOM:".$result->ID."</p>"; ?></a>
     <br>
     <div class="image-box">
       <img src="<?php echo $DND_Image;?>" alt="DND" style="width:27px;height:27px;"/>
     </div>
     <div class="image-box">
       <img src="<?php echo $CMR_Image;?>" alt="laundry" style="width:27px;height:27px;"/>
     </div>
     <div class="image-box">
       <img src="<?php echo $IRD_Image;?>" alt="makeupmyroom" style="width:27px;height:27px;"/>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

i tried $(this).attr('background-color'); on 'box'div, but with no success. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this,

```
$('#yourTableId td').on('mouseover',function(){
   var bgColor =$(this).css("background-color");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `on` to bind events to dynamically created elements.

Ex :

```
$('you table cell id').on('mouseover',function(){
   //get color of the hovered element.
})
```

This will trigger even for dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shxaz6La/)

```
$(".image-box").live("mouseover",function(){
    console.log($(this).css("backgroundColor"));
})
```

Use `$().css`

If you are using 1.9 jquery and above use `.on` instead of `.live`

Answer (score 0):

very simple

```
$("td").on("mouseover", function () {
 alert( $(this).css("background-color");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer i was looking for from https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/change-background-of-parent-div-when-hover-on-child-div-using-jquery.

As i was hovering on 'box' div, parent() got me the element i was trying to get.